# What Software was probably used to make these?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

All From WikiPedia Made by [this Guy](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Zorgit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a link to the "home wiki" where I found [**this**](http://tinyurl.com/cvgmcpb).

> What software edited the animations?
>
> Didn't completely understand your question... Did you mean what
>   graphic editor I used to create animations? None at all.
>       I used MSVC++ to write a little program that calls some GDI+ functions and draws a multi-layer TIF picture each layer of which is a
>   single frame (Only Math, C++ & some Windows API that are
>   well-documented). Then I used GIMP to convert that file from TIF to
>   GIF format and optimize it for animation.
>       This method (especially programming part) may seem a little long and dull but it's not if you have good skills in C++ and standard
>   college course of Algebraic geometry.
>       I uses this method because it is well-known for me and I don't want to learn specific editors only to create a simple picture for
>   Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which tool exactly was used here: there is at least a couple of them around :). First that comes to my mind is [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/) (free in both meanings of the word :)). Second would be [Cabri](http://www.cabri.com/). If you'd look some more, I'm sure you'd find another apps to do that and more in the field of geometry.

As a sidenote: I think it'll be best to just ask the author of these animations what soft did he used.

Comment: The reason for the downvote, please? :)

Comment: Left handed careless controlling of ipad.

Comment: That is a good reason ;D